# "can't afford to (or don't want to)" or "can't afford (or don't want) to"

Tags: grammar, word-order

Is one of the following preferable to the other:

*can't afford to (or don't want to)*

*can't afford (or don't want) to*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's mostly a matter of preference.  Personally, I much prefer the former, since it flows better: *can't afford to (or don't want to)*.